# How to use jQuery:replace() for different inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contains, pre

I have the following HTML content.

```
<pre class="preContent"> Just import all required libraries into the application. Make sure to use <String> tags. </pre>
```

I want to change the color of '**import**' and '**libraries**' and '**<**'. '**>**'.

I am trying to use jQuery:contains()..

```
 $(".preContent:contains(import)").each(function () {
        var regex = new RegExp('import','gi');
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, "<span class='red'>import</span>"));
 });
```

As per the above code, I am able to change the color of 'import' keyword. But how can I change color of other required keywords ?

Answer (score 1):

You can target multiple selectors separated by commas and then use a regex and a pattern to replace them:

```js
var regex = /(import|libraries)/gi;

$('.preContent:contains(import), .preContent:contains(libraries)').each(function() {  
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, "<span class='red'>$1</span>"));
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="preContent">Just import all required libraries into the application. Make sure to use &lt;String&gt; tags.</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you Agustin, but how to handle '<' and '>' is there any way to change the color of these symbols ? even I don't want to write &lt; or &gt; in my HTML text, because every time i need to be very careful while typing the tags.

Comment: And will it be possible to give different colors to different keywords of my choice ?